# Check if string has digits

Tags: java

How to check if passCode contains digits? I have to use the method isDigit()
I know how to check only one character with charAt() , but not with the entire word.

```
public class CheckingPasscodes {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
       boolean hasDigit = false;
       String passCode = "";
       int valid = 0;

       passCode = "abc";

       // if (?)
       hasDigit = true;

       if (hasDigit) {
          System.out.println("Has a digit.");
       } else {
          System.out.println("Has no digit.");
       }
       return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop to check every character in the passcode

```
hasDigit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < passCode.length(); ++i) {
        if (Character.isDigit(passCode.charAt(i))) {
            hasDigit = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Using regex can help you:

```
hasDigit = passCode.matches(".*\\d+.*");
```

Comment: Point of pedantry: This will fail to detect digits if the string also contains any [line terminator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt) because `.` by default does not match them. It can be fixed if desired by replacing `.` with `[\S\s]`. I.e. `hasDigit = passCode.matches("[\\S\\s]*\\d+[\\S\\s]*");`. Or more neatly, use the `Pattern` class directly to side-step the restriction that `String.matches` always tries to match the entire string: `hasDigit = java.util.Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(passCode).find();`

Answer (score -3):

```
for (int i=0;i<=passcode.length();i++)
char a=passcode.charAt(i);
if (a.isDigit())
    System.out.print("Has digit");
else
    System.out.print("No digits found");
```

Comment: That would work IF the String class had a "hasDigit" method.

Comment: @marks i fixed it :-)

Comment: no it would not work either way because it would throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and even if that was not a problem there are no braces.  Also `char` is a primitive type it has no methods. And even then it would only just assign `a` over and over again and then test the last one, which does not count as working. This is why you **always** use braces.